# Exclude folder from results in SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using a REST API to get the list of all files inside a document library.

However, this also brings the list of all folders.

Is there a way to filter out the folders and bring only the files using the REST API?

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Library Name')/items?$top=1000&$select=Title,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef/Title&$expand=FieldValuesAsText",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //some code
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few more options actually available:

> items?$top=1000&$select=Title,FileLeafRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef/Title&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=FSObjType eq 0

`FSObjType` (display name `Item Type`) is a built-in field, values are based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filesystemobjecttype.aspx) enumeration

OR

> items?$top=1000&$select=Title,FileLeafRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef/Title&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId, '0x0101')

Later approach uses content type and filters out only items which are File-based content type (`0x0101`)

Comment: Thanks! this approach worked for me, however, I didnt need to expand by "FieldValuesAsText", all I had was to filter by "FSObjType eq 0"

Answer (score 2):

you can use this snip of code to filter your results and exclude `Folders`

```
var g;  
$.ajax({  
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Training Material')/Items",  
type: 'GET',  
dataType: "json",  
headers: {  
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",  
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
},  
success: function (data) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {  
        if (data.d.results[i].FileSystemObjectType != 1) {            
        }  
    }  
},  
error: function (request, error) {  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request));  
}  
});
```

The above code will return all the items of document library including folders. So, to exclude folders, we can use `FileSystemObjectType` property to determind whether the current item is folder or file. For more information on FileSystemObjectType, visit [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filesystemobjecttype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the REST URL and point to the document library.
data.Files property will contain only the files and data.Folders will contain the folders.

```
var RestUrl= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents')?$expand=Folders,Files";      //document library name

    $.getJSON(RestUrl,function(data,status,xhr){

        if(data.Files.length > 0)
        {
        var results = data.Files;
        }
    });
```

The above code is tested and works fine.